# It's possible to access to specific child type?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a file input inside a div, and I would like to access to it, but the file input has no id.

```js
        var el = $("#hey > :file");
    console.log(el);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="something" id="hey">
  <div class="remote"></div>
  <input type="file">
</div>
```

But I get a lot of elements, I would like to know if it's possible to do without jQuery.

Comment: document.querySelector('input[type=file').files[0].name gives you the name.

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="file">` can be matched by the selector `input[type="file"]`, so use that next the `#hey >`.

You don't need jQuery, `querySelector` works just fine.

```js
var el = document.querySelector('#hey > input[type="file"]');
console.log(el);

el.onchange = () => {
  console.log(el.files);
};
```

```html
<div class="something" id="hey">
  <div class="remote"></div>
  <input type="file">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But using this I can't access to input file using: el[0].files[0], why?

Comment: `el` is the *element itself*, not a jQuery collection - you said you wanted to do it without jQuery. `querySelector` returns just an element, not a collection - so access the element's `.files` property.

Comment: I see, so I should do el.files? I have tried but returns empty "Filelist". Thanks

Comment: It will be empty if you retrieve the value before the user selects a file. If you retrieve the value after the user selects a file, it'll show the file as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelector()` to get first match element, or if you need list of all elements use `document.querySelectorAll()`

```js
var el = document.querySelector('#hey > input[type="file"]');
    console.log(el);
```

```html
<div class="something" id="hey">
  <div class="remote"></div>
  <input type="file">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But using this I can't access to input file using: el[0].files[0], why?

Comment: because `el` is an element, not an array, so it's `el.files[0]`